# Sitecore 6.5 XML control script insertion Vulnerability

Tags: xml, security, sitecore, xss, sitecore6

We are using Sitecore 6.5 and have been alerted to an XSS vulnerability: http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-100004.  I cannot find any resolution other than upgrading to Sitecore 7, so thought I would ask here just in case someone knew of another way.  We are planning to upgrade, but it is a long way off due to the complexity of the site and certain customizations that were made.  Are we stuck with this vulnerability until an upgrade?  Also, would this affect both the CM and CD or just the CM?  Some of the information seems to suggest it's mainly a vulnerability for the CM.  We've separated the CM and CD to use two different servers and we even have different database users for each in order to minimize the permissions to only those needed by each.

Comment: I would suggest you raise a ticket with Sitecore Support if you have not done so already.

Comment: I suggest you to make an upgrade from 6.5. A security bug is this one and is applying to 6.5 : https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/020736

Comment: I've notified our internal security team and hope to get a response from them or product support here shortly.

I would strongly recommend that you raise a support ticket on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested; you really need to look at getting an upgrade project going. Sitecore 6 isn't officially supported unless you purchase special support subscriptions with Sitecore. That said...

The vulnerability you mention doesn't indicate to me, that it would affect just the CM - at least not in default configurations. Have you tested for this?  Try some of the examples listed on the vulnerability document.

http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/530901/100/0/threaded

If you can indeed reproduce the problem on both your CM and CD servers, there may be a workaround in, removing the targeted subsystem from your CD configuration. This is speculation on my part though - so do make sure you test and re-test.

```
<control template="xmlcontrol" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControlRenderingType, Sitecore.Kernel" propertyMap="controlName=control name, properties=parameters"/>
```

Find this in your configuration and remove it (from CD). If it closes the problem, you're at least set for a temporary workaround. Your CM box will probably not function with this disabled, so you'll have to shield it behind firewall for now. Good practice anyway.